# How to manage concurrent API Calls throughout the lifetime of an application

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency

At the moment i am trying to find the best way to manage concurrent API Calls within my application. Currently i have been using HTTPURLConnection to make my HTTP method calls and although it works fine, eventually i would come across some 'Socket exception: connection reset' whilst calls are being made. however, i am using multithreading as i have many different api calls running concurrently.

I have looked into using AsyncRestTemplate and although it is working i find that in the console a list of the pool and thread is shown i.e [pool-6-thread-1] however when it becomes [pool-2018-thread-1] that is when it decides to stop making any more api calls.

This is the code that i am using:

```
//This method is inside another class in my actual application but here for simplicity

public static ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> getLastPrice( AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate) {

    String url = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-dar";

    asyncRestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate(new ConcurrentTaskExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

    return asyncRestTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>("result"), String.class);

}

public PriceThread(JTextField lastPriceJT) {

    this.lastPriceJT = lastPriceJT;

}

@Override
public void run() {

    AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate(new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor());

    while (true) {

        try {
            getLastPrice(coin, asyncRestTemplate)
                    .addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> response) {
                            //TODO: Add real response handling
                            try {

                                JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response.getBody());

                                String status = LOGGER.printResponseToLogger(result);

                                BigDecimal last = result.getJSONArray("result").getJSONObject(0).getBigDecimal("Last");

                                lastPriceJT.setText(last.toPlainString());

                            } catch (Exception e) {

                                LOGGER.printResponseToLogger(e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                            //TODO: Add real logging solution

                            LOGGER.printResponseToLogger(ex.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.printResponseToLogger(e.getMessage());

        }

    }
}
```

Currently i'm thinking the solution to this issue would be for me to reuse the pools so that it doesn't increment to 2018 if that is possible but i have not found a way to do so.

Comment: Stop using static methods. Make a singleton spring bean of type AsyncRestTemplate, inject it wherever you need it, use it, instead of constantly creating new pools and new AsyncRestTemplate instances.

Comment: There's no apparent reason on why it'd stop on 2018. Does it stop there consistently? The only limit should be that imposed by the thread-pool or the OS (if no more TCP/IP ports can be opened). But they should both be way greater than 2018. The getLastPrice() seems to ignore the rest-template passed to it - is this the actual code you are running? If not, please supply the actual code.

Comment: @JBNizet can you make an answer out of that so i can accept